# Is it possible to simulate low GPS accuracy in Xcode or device?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, gps

I need to allow manual positioning over a map if user location remains under a given accuracy a certain amount of time.

I need a way to test this circumstance. It's not like disable location services. Just want to have bad GPS signal (for example: horizontalAccuracy about 500 m. or so). "Unfortunately", in the place I work (my own house) I have a strong GPS signal so I can't test and fine tune the app behavior.

I wonder if there's a way to do this. Something like the network link conditioner in the developer menu on iPhone settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to do it short of writing a test class to inject location data.  (I.e., there's nothing in the location simulation functionality provided by the simulator and/or debugger that will allow you to set accuracy.)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14914381/225176) to a similar question has an example of the manual-test-class-hackery way.

Comment: Thank you Arkaaito. I already knew that answer but I wanted to know if there was an "official" way to do it.